# How can I encrypt & sign a string and submit to an external url in laravel 9

Tags: php, ssl, encryption, rsa, laravel-9

This is my string;

```
$data = 'stringA' . 'stringB';
```

So I created an encrypt function;

```
// Encrypt String using Public Certificate
            function encrypt($plainText, $publicCertificatePath)
            {
                $cert = file_get_contents($publicCertificatePath);
                $cert = openssl_x509_read($cert);
                $publicKey = openssl_get_publickey($cert);
                // openssl_free_key($cert);

                $cipherText = '';
                openssl_public_encrypt($plainText, $cipherText, $publicKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);

                return base64_encode($cipherText);
            }
```

and encrypted the string below;

```
// public certificate was provided by the URL I am submitting data to
 $encryptedCredentials = encrypt($data, storage_path('app/certificates/public-cert.pem'));
```

Then I generate a private certificate;

```
function generateCertificate($commonName, $countryName, $stateOrProvinceName, $localityName, $organizationName, $organizationalUnitName, $emailAddress, $outputPath)
            {
                // Generate private key
                $process = new Process([
                    'openssl',
                    'genpkey',
                    '-algorithm',
                    'RSA',
                    '-out',
                    $outputPath . '.key.pem',
                    '-aes256',
                    '-pass',
                    'pass:password',
                    '-outform',
                    'PEM'
                ]);
                $process->run();
                if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
                    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
                }
                // Generate CSR
                $process = new Process([
                    'openssl',
                    'req',
                    '-new',
                    '-key',
                    $outputPath . '.key.pem',
                    '-out',
                    $outputPath . '.csr.pem',
                    '-passin',
                    'pass:password',
                    '-subj',
                    "/C=$countryName/ST=$stateOrProvinceName/L=$localityName/O=$organizationName/OU=$organizationalUnitName/CN=$commonName/emailAddress=$emailAddress"
                ]);
                $process->run();
                if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
                    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
                }
                // Generate self-signed certificate
                $process = new Process([
                    'openssl',
                    'x509',
                    '-req',
                    '-days',
                    '365',
                    '-in',
                    $outputPath . '.csr.pem',
                    '-signkey',
                    $outputPath . '.key.pem',
                    '-out',
                    $outputPath . '.cert.pem',
                    '-passin',
                    'pass:password'
                ]);
                $process->run();
                if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
                    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
                }
            }

generateCertificate('name', 'UG', 'state', 'Location', 'frd', 'Ecom', 'myemail@gmail.com', storage_path('app/certificates/'));
```

Then I used the private key to sign the $encryptedCredentials

```
 // Sign String using MDA Private Certificate
            function signString(string $text, string $privateKeyPath, string $passphrase): string
            {
                // Load private key
                $privateKey = openssl_get_privatekey(file_get_contents($privateKeyPath), $passphrase);

                // Sign the string
                openssl_sign($text, $signature, $privateKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

                // Free the key from memory
                openssl_free_key($privateKey);

                // Return the signature as a base64-encoded string
                return base64_encode($signature);
            }

            // sign using MDA private certificate.
            $signedCredentials = signString($encryptedCredentials, storage_path('app/certificates/private.pem'), '');
```

I was provided with a URL from the provider;

```
$url = "https://urlfromprovider";
```

Finally, I try to send the request

```
$data = [];

$postData = http_build_query($data);

            // return $postData;

            $opts = array(
                'http' =>
                array(
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'header'  => "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n",
                    'content' => $postData
                )
            );

            $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

            $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context, 40000);

            return $response;
```

Where could I have gone wrong I keep receiving 400 Bad request, yet I'm submitting the exact data requested by the provider.

Comment: Why does the provider require you to encrypt the data again when using [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS)?

Comment: It's just part of their security 

Comment: OK, then where do you actually encrypt the data in your request? Why an offset of 40,000 when you send it? This all makes very little sense to me.